Get latest version of GitHub Repo in JavaScript
I'm looking to build a function into an existing JS software toolset that can read the latest release version of the toolset itself from GitHub.
I have a JS function already to read what the currently installed version is (from the ReadMe), and I want to compare the current version against the latest available on the repo.
Possibly reading the ReadMe file from the master branch of the GitHub could work, but I don't know how to read in a file as text from a URL. The Repo is private / has Auth token requirement too.

You can't do this from frontend JavaScript, that's for certain. For Node.js, there are GitHub API libraries.

Is the goal to have a kind of private package management system?  It may be easier to look into hosting a private npm registry instead of this manual effort.
